# Why do tensions cancel out in some places but not others?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I was answering a question regarding two rotating particles $P$ and $Q$ with $P$ attached to a fixed point $O$ by a light inextensible string and $Q$ attached to $P$ by a light inextensible string with $P$ and $Q$ rotating about the vertical through $O$ in the same vertical plane and at constant angles to the vertical:
[image]

If I consider the whole system and consider the forces acting on the vertical plane I believe I get something like this:
[image]

Even if this is slightly wrong I know that I consider the tension $T_{1}$ acting in the direction $\vec{PO}$ but not in the direction $\vec{PQ}$ because it is cancelled out by the tension in the direction $\vec{QP}$ which is equal and opposite. My question is therefore why is there not an equal and opposite tension in the direction $\vec{OP}$ that cancels out $T_{1}$. Is it the fact that $O$ is a fixed point rather than a particle? If so why does this make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering the whole system to be both particle $P$ and $Q$, then this makes sense. You are only drawing external forces in your second picture. The tension between $P$ and $Q$ is an internal force, so you have not drawn it. However, the tension between $P$ and $O$ is an external force, so you have drawn it.

If you wanted to "get rid of" the tension between $P$ and $O$ you would need to include point $O$ (whatever it is physically) in your system. However, you would then also need to consider all of the other forces acting on $O$ that keeps in fixed in space. So you would get rid of the tension between $P$ and $O$ from your diagram, but you would then include other forces acting on $O$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must be precise with your system. I am assuming you are interested in knowing the forces acting on particle **P**, then forces on particle **P** are a)gravity downwards b)Both tensions T1 and T2 c)D'lemberts force axially outward on particle **P**. Don't confuse with tension T2. It pulls particle **P** towards right and particle **Q** towards left side. If you are selecting particle **P** as your system then there is no need to consider the tension with which particle **P** is pulling the string(which is just opposite to the tension with which string is pulling **P**). **Just consider the external forces acting on the system, ignore all forces including which system may be applying to outside.**